# How to use multiple attractors to move objects with Geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a node setup that will allow me to effect the density of a set number of instances along a curve with multiple attractors.  I have a setup using one attractor that is working pretty well, however, I can't implement any more without causing strange effects that I can't solve.

Bonus points if you can tell me how to restrict the movement of the instances so that they do not move beyond the curve from which they are instanced on.

[image]

The second attractor isn't hooked up here, but it would usually just be plugged into the second set position node

[image: The second attractor isn't hooked up here, but it would usually just be plugged into the second set position node]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert several objects from a collection into points and use them for `Geometry Proximity`.

You can then use the resulting distance value as a multiplier of the direction to the nearest object.

Something like this:

[image]

Note: This solution is not perfect, however, because too large an area of effect will move an object either one way or the other, depending on which object is closer.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.6+)*</sub>